# How to get average an attribute of an array in mongodb (mongoose)

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongodb-query

please help me, I'm trying to get near sellers by users location input and then sort by average rating. Is it possible?
This is the snippet of the model. Model has an array of reviews.

```
    const sellerSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        _id: Mongoose....ObjectId
            //... 
        reviews: [
        {
          by: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "User",
          },
          title: {
            type: String,
          },
          message: {
            type: String,
          },
          rating: Number,
          imagesUri: [{ String }],
          timestamp: {
            type: Date,
            default: Date.now,
          },
        },
      ],
    });
```

Then my aggregate I have:

```
const seller = await Seller.aggregate(
    [
      {
        $geoNear: {
          near: {
            type: "Point",
            coordinates: [longitude, latitude],
          },
          distanceField: "distance",
          spherical: true,
          maxDistance: radius,
        },
      },
      rating_minimum ? { $match: { rating: { $gt: rating_minimum } } } 
       : {},
      {$limit: limit},
    ]);
```

I was thinking of $group and create avgReview, and then sort them by reviews something like:

```
{$group:{averageReviews: { $avg: "$reviews.rating"}},
{$sort: { averageReviews: 1 } },
{$limit: limit}
```

Comment: how does your user model looks like

Comment: @Ifaruki I just edited, finally I figured how to put code here lol please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the reviews are in array per document, instead of `$group` which collect documents, you can use `$reduce` to calculate the average rating:

```
 {
    $addFields: {
      ratingSum: {
        $reduce: {
          initialValue: 0,
          input: "$reviews",
          in: {$sum: ["$$value", "$$this.rating"]}
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      "averageReviews": {"$divide": ["$ratingSum", {$size: "$reviews"}]
      }
    }
  },
  {$sort: { averageReviews: 1 } },
  {$limit: limit}
```

As you can see on [this playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/gNISv_F8ciO).

I'm not sure about what your are trying to limit for 3, but if it is the final results, 3 sellers, than you are using it correctly.

BTW, your seller schema is missing the location of the seller, needed for the `$geoNear`.

Comment: That's great! Yeah the location I did not put because I did not want to confuse anyone with it lol Thanks! This does work exactly. Wow! Also, thanks for the helpful mongo playground. I can actually work and see the results for future queries. Thank you so much again!